# How can i hide the location and status bar in Mozilla firefox in javascript

Tags: javascript

In a project i use the following code to open a window:

```
window.open(href, 'mysite' ,'width=401,height=380,directories=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, location=no, resizable=no, menubar=no, status=no')
```

But Mozilla firefox and IE always show the location bar and Status bar. How can i hide those?

Comment: You *really* need to go through your old questions and accept the best answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't any more. Those bars can not be disabled anymore due to security restrictions. It was too easy for malicious sites to fake what web site the user was on.

You could use "inline" dialogs like [**JQuery dialog**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog). They are HTML elements within the current page, fully configurable and also immune against pop-up blockers.